# How to store LogRecords instances to be formatted later?

Tags: python, logging

I want to store any LogRecords created during my application's flow. Instead of formatting them to a string the instance they are created, I want to store them in a list and format them later.

Some context to it:
I want to create an HTML report for these logs, and each log record should be in its own span and get a class that contains its log level. It will be easier to do so if I will have access to the LogRecord instance instead of splitting strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a handler that stores the log records in an external list and examine it later:

```
import logging


# A new handler to store "raw" LogRecords instances
class RecordsListHandler(logging.Handler):
    """
    A handler class which stores LogRecord entries in a list
    """
    def __init__(self, records_list):
        """
        Initiate the handler
        :param records_list: a list to store the LogRecords entries
        """
        self.records_list = records_list
        super().__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.records_list.append(record)


# A list to store the "raw" LogRecord instances
logs_list = []

# Your logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the RecordsListHandler to store the log records objects
logger.addHandler(RecordsListHandler(logs_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.debug('debug message')
    logger.info('info message')

    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] | %(module)-10s | %(funcName)-10s | %(levelname)-7s : %(message)s',
                                  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    html_logs_section = ''
    for log_record in logs_list:
        html_logs_section += f'<span class="{log_record.levelname}">{formatter.format(log_record)}</span><br>'

    print(html_logs_section)
```